# Most common value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with some books. These are the fields:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| book             | genre    | author             |
----------------------------------------------------
----------------------------------------------------
| The DaVinci code | thriller | Dan Brown          |
----------------------------------------------------
| Odd Thomas       | horror   | Dean Kunz          |
----------------------------------------------------
| Fairy Tales      | child    | The Grimm brothers |
----------------------------------------------------
| Inferno          | thriller | Dan Brown          |
----------------------------------------------------
| Digital Fortres  | sci-fi   | Dan Brown          |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to get "Dan Brown" as the author with most books in the table. Can you help me how? Thank you

Comment: How do you want to handle those with duplicate counts. Say Dean Kunz existed twice more in your example? Should both show? The first alphabetically by name?

Comment: Only the most appearing author

Comment: You're missing the point. What happens if two authors appear the exact same amount. Do you want both or just one of them. If just one, how should the system determine which one? If just one and you don't care which, AdrianBR's answer is what you're after.

Comment: sorry :) I got the point now. Thank you and AdrianBR for the help

Comment: @crazyname NP, in case two authors have the same number of entries, my query will return the first result in alphabetical order, unless specified otherwise in the order clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select author -- what you select
from table -- from where
group by author -- grouping on author so you can get count of entries for each author
order by count(*) desc -- order by the number of entries descending
limit 1 -- keep first row only
```